# Tic Tac Toe Game- Can Not Assign to Function Call

Tags: python, syntax-error, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a Tic Tac Toe game on python so far I've come up with a pretty solid code but I'm getting an error at one point that I am unable to fix.

Here's the code:

```
from random import randint

List=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

def board(List):
    print('=== Tic Tac Toe ===')
    for i in range(3):
        print('   ',List[i][0],'  ',List[i][1],'   ',List[i][2])

def usr_choice(i,f,List):
    while List[i][f]!=0:
        i,f =eval(input('Please enter correct choice i or f: '))
    List[i][f]=2

def comp_choice(List):
    i=randint(0,2),f=randint(0,2)
    while List[i][f]!=0:
        i=randint(0,2),f=randint(0,2)
    List[i][f]=1
     
def decision(List):
    if [List[i][i] for i in range(3)]==[2,2,2] or \
        [List[2-i][i] for i in range(3)]==[2,2,2]: 
            print('You win!')
            return True
    elif[List[i][i] for i in range(3)]==[1,1,1] or \
        [List[2-i][i] for i in range(3)]==[1,1,1]: 
            print('You lose!')
            return True
    else: 
        for i in range(3):
            if [List [i][:]for i in range(3)]==[2,2,2] or \
                [List[f][i] for j in range(3)]==[2,2,2]:
                    print('You win!')
                    return True
            elif [List [i][:]for i in range(3)]==[1,1,1] or \
                [List[f][i] for j in range(3)]==[1,1,1]:
                    print('You lose!')
                    return True
```

This is the error I am receiving under def comp_choice(List):

```
 i=randint(0,2),j=randint(0,2)
   ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

Comment: In python the this line is equivalent to `i=(randint(0,2),j)=randint(0,2)` which assigning to a function call (`randint(0,2)`). What you need to do is to split this into 2 lines: `i = randint(0, 2)` `j = randint(0, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare multiple variables in the same assignment, do:

```py
i, j = randint(0, 2), randint(0, 2)
```

To declare multiple variable in different assignments but in the same row, do:

```py
i = randint(0, 2); j = randint(0, 2)
```